# Implement different return types from an interface using generics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, generics, interface

I have an interface defined like this:

```
public interface ISomeOrderService
{
    T GetUserNameandPass<T>();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> FetchOrdersAsync<T>(bool useProxy, bool impersonateProxyUser);
}
```

For the `GetUserNameandPass`, I want it to return the following object in the implementing class:

```
public class NameandPass
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

On the other hand, for the `FetchOrdersAsync`, I want it to return the following object in the implementing class:

```
public class SomeOrder
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime prop2 { get; set; }
    internal static async Task<IEnumerable<SomeOrder>> ConvertServiceResponseToSomeOrderListAsync(SomeResponse someResponse)
    {
        //someResult
        return someResult.ToList();
    }
}
```

I have my implementing class that looks like this:

```
public class SomeOrderService : ISomeOrderService
{
    private IAMSService _aMSService;
    public SomeOrderService()
    {
        _aMSService = new AMSService();
    }
    public NameandPass GetUserNameandPass()
    {
        return _aMSService.GetProxyUser<NameandPass>("SomeTypeOfUser");
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<SomeOrder>> FetchOrdersAsync<SomeOrder>(bool useProxy, bool impersonateProxyUser)
    {
        //someResponse;
        return await SomeOrder.ConvertServiceResponseToSomeOrderListAsync(someResponse);
    }
}
```

Here I have this first error in line:

`return await SomeOrder.ConvertServiceResponseToSomeOrderListAsync(someResponse);`

```
SomeOrder is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context.
```

And the other error comes in the `AMSService`:

```
public class AMSService : IAMSService
{
    public NameandPass GetProxyUser<NameandPass>(string proxyUser)
    {
        //someProxyUserResultObject
        return new NameandPass { UserName = someProxyUserResultObject.Username, Password = someProxyUserResultObject.Password };
    }
}
```

Here I get this second error:

```
AMSService doesn't implement member 'IAMSService.GetProxyUser<T>(string)'. 'AMSService.GetProxyUser<NameandPass>(string)' cannot implement 'IAMSService.GetProxyUser<T>(string)' because it does not have matching return type of 'T'.'
```

The `IAMSService.cs` looks like this:

```
public interface IAMSService
{
    T GetProxyUser<T>(string proxyUser);
}
```

What could I be doing wrong here? Is my Interface definition from the start not adequate?

Thank You for the help!

Comment: You don't want generics for this. The methods in the interface should declare the return types you've indicated. Also, your `SomeOrderService`'s `FetchOrdersAsync` implementation is defining a type parameter called `SomeOrder`. It's not referring to the `SomeOrder` class. Change the color for "User Types - Type Parameters" (I use Olive) and you'll see that it's not the same thing.

Comment: Hi @madreflection, thank you for the comment but I do not want to specify return types in the interface because I'm only adding interfaces in a class library to an existing project which has their separate project with models already defined and I don't want to define redundant models in the interfaces class library project yet again. It's an effort to avoid circular dependency, that's why I'm adding these interfaces now. So I was hoping to get help from generics for this. And is there a way how I could fix these errors?

Comment: Generics won't help with that. Start with redundant models and then refactor or, better yet, extract the models to a common dependency.

Comment: Ok thank you @madreflection , I'll try the path with the redundant models for now. I was hoping to get cleaner approach but I guess I don't have it for now. Thank you for the direction though.